# Error running heroku console. can't update heroku

Tags: heroku, rubygems

When I try to run heroku console I get the following error:

```
user@omnipresent:~/rails/demo$ heroku console
 !   This version of the heroku gem has been deprecated.
 !   Please update it by running: gem update heroku
```

When I do the update..it says there is nothing to update!

```
user@omnipresent:~/rails/demo$ gem update heroku
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

Following are my versions:

```
user@omnipresent:~/rails/demo$ heroku version
heroku-gem/1.5.2
user@omnipresent:~/rails/demo$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p0 (2009-01-30 revision 21907) [i686-linux]
user@omnipresent:~/rails/demo$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
```

running heroku list shows following:

```
user@omnipresent:/usr/bin$ gem list heroku

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

heroku (1.8.5, 1.8.3, 1.8.0, 1.5.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I already had 1.8.5...I guess installing it again forces the class cache update.

```
user@omnipresent:~/rails/seconddemo$ sudo gem install heroku
Successfully installed heroku-1.8.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for heroku-1.8.5...
Updating class cache with 3098 classes...
Installing RDoc documentation for heroku-1.8.5...
user@omnipresent:~/rails/seconddemo$ heroku console
Ruby console for myapp.heroku.com
>>
```